# How to set "Default Landing Page" in an ORG

Tags: lightning, landing-page

I was trying to set one of my Apps in the org as a default landing page for a particular profile. I made the necessary changes i.e making the App as default for the profile in "APP MANAGER" and in "PROFILE SETTINGS" of that particular profile. However it Seems that the Landing page is coming up based on which app user had selected when he logged of last time,  so  When he logs in next, same the landing app is the one which was selected last time(not the default app ). Am I missing any other setting here or is this Salesforce behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce remembers the user's last selected app and always sends them back to that app when they login again. There isn't a way to always have them start in a specific app.